# MS-SQL multiple like query

Tags: sql-server

I have two Input textboxes:-BookName and Author

I am trying to use a store procedure for searching in Library Management System.
Procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Library_AdvSearch
    (
        @BookName varchar(50),
        @Author varchar(50)

    )
AS
    Select * from Library_Book 
    where ( BookName Like '%'+ @BookName +'%' OR Author Like '%'+@Author+'%')

RETURN
```

this produces an ambiguos result and displays all the data pertaining table

now my question is: i want to redesign my query in such a way that if i dont insert any value in Bookname, and only define author, it should show me respective table entry

my table looks like

```
BOOk name|Author
C        |qwerty
let us C |asdfg
java     |xyz
```

now if i input only xyz ,it should display java and xyz in gridview

so please help me in store procedure

any help will be appreciated

Comment: BookName Like  @BookName +'%' OR Author Like @Author+'%'

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Library_AdvSearch
(
    @BookName varchar(50) = '',
    @Author varchar(50) = ''
)
AS
Select * from Library_Book 
WHERE((@BookName = '' OR BookName Like '%'+ @BookName +'%')
AND (@Author = '' OR Author Like '%'+@Author+'%'))

RETURN
```

Comment: thnx 4 help,,,but still it's producing ambiguous result when i try to feed "xyz" as author's input..I dont know why itz behaving lyk this

Comment: How you are passing your textbox values to your sp, please share that code also.

Comment: protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataclass ob = new dataclass();
        if (Panel1.Visible != false)
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = ob.LibraryBookSearch(TxtSearch.Text); ;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            
        }
        else
        {
            
            GridView1.DataSource= ob.LibraryBookSearchAdv(TxtSearch.Text,TxtAuthor.Text,TxtPubYear.Text,TxtPublication.Text);
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

Comment: here panel is for advance search toggle

Comment: In Sp, you need to check with `AND` instead of `OR`, I Guess.

Comment: i tried it with AND also,,,,still troubling me,,,listen what am trying to say is if i feed only AUTHOR value,,,and keep BOOKNAME data blank,,,it shows me error that @BOOKNAME parameter not supplied,,plz help me

Comment: I have update the answer try with providing default blank string to your parameters like  `@BookName varchar(50) = '', @Author varchar(50) = ''`. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave `@BookName` empty, you're basically searching for `BookName Like '%'`, in other words: all the books.

I would go with a single parameter:

```
select * from Library_Book 
where ( BookName Like '%'+ @Parameter +'%' OR Author Like '%'+ @Parameter +'%')
```

Comment: what if i change the property of textbox and set default value as single space "" ,,will that be ok?

Comment: Depending on where you use that, it will give you Books with a title or Author containing the blank. If you have full names in the Author field ("Firstname Lastname") your query will return all those authors.

Comment: listen what am trying to say is if i feed only AUTHOR value,,,and keep BOOKNAME data blank,,,it shows me error that @BOOKNAME parameter not supplied,,plz help me

Comment: I understand, but if you specify a parameter, you cannot omit it. Please try the idea above with ONE parameter handling both fields.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is matching all books/authors when they're blank and you want to exclude them.  So change the OR to AND so it meets all criteria.
Not sure if I've understood you correctly though.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Library_AdvSearch
        (
            @BookName varchar(50),
            @Author varchar(50)

        )
    AS
        Select * from Library_Book 
        where ( BookName Like '%'+ @BookName +'%' AND Author Like '%'+@Author+'%')

    RETURN
```

Comment: thnx 4 help,,,,but wat if i feed input for author only,,and not for bookname,,,in that situation it shows an error that bookname is not supplied,,,plz help :(

Comment: Sorry mate, but nobody can help you properly with "it shows an error".  Post your error message!!  Sounds like you have an error at the client side though.  Also, as I've written it you need to pass '' not NULL but that's probably further down the track.

Comment: it is mentioned above,,,,styl m specifying it again,,error is "@BOOKNAME parameter is not supplied" when i try to pass only "XYZ" as author's value,,according to my table it should return a field(see table in question for reference),,,,,plz help